# Insert Hibernate NamedQuery with embedded field

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, sql-insert, named-query

I have this :

```
public class A {

    private B b; 

    @Embedded
    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class B {

    private String b1;
    private String b2;

    //constructor
    //accessors
}

@NamedQuery(name = "create", query = "insert into A(b1) values ('test')")
```

But I get this error :

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: b1 of: com.blabla.A
```

I don't know how to call attributes of my embedded class and i don't find any example on the internet. Do someone know how I can call b1 attribute ?

Thanks.

Comment: The class A has not attribute b1. Its attribute is called b.

Comment: Yes but because of B is embedded i shoud be able to access b1 right ?
I tried insert into A(B.b1) values ... too

Answer (score 0):

Try whit this:

```
public class A {
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides(value={
   @AttributeOverride(name = "b1", @Column()),
   @AttributeOverride(name = "b2", @Column())
})
private B b; 


public B getB() {
    return b;
}

public void setB(B b) {
    this.b = b;
}}
```

And your `NamedQuery` must works: `@NamedQuery(name = "create", query = "insert into A(b1) values ('test')")`